# Access localhost web application in network

Tags: java, networking, ip, port

I have deployed a web application in Apache tomcat server. Now I can use application in `http://localhost:port_Number/appName`.

I want to access appName from another computer which is connected in LAN. 
I can see references involving WAMP, but I am simply using Apache tomcat.

Comment: Is your server listening to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`? If so, get it to listen to `0.0.0.0` instead, so that it listens on your LAN interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to know your IP address of your server in your LAN. So you can access your server app like

> http://192.168.1.100:8080/appName

Where 192.168.1.100 is your IP and "8080" is Tomcat Server port. After this, you have to check, if your Tomcat Server is listening to your LAN IP.